# How do i Deploy HttpHandlers in asp.net 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, ihttphandler, http-verbs

Question:

How does one deploy a HttpHandler in asp.net 2.0?

#### Updated Http Handler code (Inside App_Code):

```
namespace Samples
{
    public class SampleHandler : IHttpHandler
    {    
        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            context.Response.Write("Hello World");
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Updated Web.Config file

```
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" type="Samples.SampleHandler" path="*.js"/>
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
```

#### aspx page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/sample.js"></script>
```

as you see every javascript request must be routed to the http handler but it doesn't.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621391/serve-javascript-file-via-http-handler

Comment: @V4Vendetta that never helped me, did you read through the post correctly.Explain me then why httpHandlers are not processed `when i request the javascript file`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228090.aspx).

Comment: nothing is wrong with my implementation. But the request does not get routed into the HttpHandler you got any more answers?

Comment: @Deeptechtons, are you running this in IIS or the built-in server? Also why is your handler decorated with the `[WebService]` and `[WebServiceBinding]` attributes? Those are used when you are writing an asmx web service which you aren't. Also did you reads the article I have linked in my answer? If you are trying to host this in IIS 6 or IIS 7 (classic mode) you need a wildcard mapping.

Comment: thanks for the correction, please look at new code now. I did Build Rebuild Solution and requested the page again. Nothing happens, what wrong am i doing? btw IIS 6

Comment: @Deeptechtons, in IIS you need to register a [wildcard mapping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb515343.aspx) so that the .js extension is associated with the aspnet_isapi filter. There is nothing wrong with your code. You need to configure your web server.

Comment: dose IIS 5.1 support wildcard mappings, because i can't find them in my iis management console

Answer (score 2):

To get asp.net to respond to requests for filetypes that are not asp.net specific ones you need to ensure that a [wildcard mapping has been configured](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/03/04/tip-trick-integrating-asp-net-security-with-classic-asp-and-non-asp-net-urls.aspx) (first part of article). This ensures that IIS passes requests for files ending in `.js` to asp.net so your custom handler will be called.